# what does this jquery selector means

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

what does this jquery selector means `$("*[regex]")`

I want to select all controls which have an attribute regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's selecting all elements with a `regex=` attribute (that it's *present*, it can be empty).

Though, the [all selector](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/) can be implied, it can just be:

```
$("[regex]")
```

Both are *very* inefficient though it would be better to add the element type or *anything* to narrow it down before looking for attributes.

Comment: If I want to have a selector which have regex= and error= both attributes together

Comment: @vaibhav - Add them beside each other without a space to only select elements that have both:  `$("[regex][error]")`.

Comment: @vaibhav: you can chain strings together like `$('[regexp][error]')`

Comment: seriously, do you have a script or something that autorefreshes stackoverflow all the time? :p

Comment: @jAndy - the notification icon in the toolbar (The stackexchange one) is instant how, so I see replies quicker than before it was added, yes :)